# wordpress 3.5 limit roles available when creating a user

Tags: php, wordpress, user-roles

I have a Wordpress with 2 admin roles :

- the super admin, who can do anything
- the normal admin, who has limited acces to WP functions (everything except WP configuration). This role was created using a plugin to manage user roles.

I want to add the possibility for the normal admin to create user, but when I do the normal is able to create super admins...

Is there a way to limit the roles available when creating a user ? (plugin, PHP function using hooks...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I had the same problem and used this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

Cya

Comment: I tried this plugin at the beginning of the development, but didn't keep it and used another one (don't remember why ^^), I shouldn't have ! Thanks !